# Организация памяти в ОС

Tags: память

Здравствуйте! У меня возник вопрос с заданием :

Три процедуры A, B и C, расположенные в разных файлах, были объединены в одну программу с помощью linker'а и загружены в память. Размеры их составляют 900, 1000 и 1300 машинных слов соответственно. Рассмотрим следующие схемы управления памятью:

a) Страничная организация (без сегментации). Размер страницы - 1000 слов, таблица страниц занимает одну страницу.

b) Сегментная организация (без страниц). Для каждой процедуры используется свой сегмент памяти. Таблица сегментов занимает 1000 слов.

c) Сегментно-страничная организация. Комбинация информации из пунктов a) и b).

Для всех трех схем организации определите количество памяти, требующееся программе для ее полной загрузки в оперативную память (т.е. для загрузки процедур и всех необходимых таблиц).

Я читал про эти организации, но не совсем понимаю, от чего отталкиваться при решении. Буду признателен за любые подсказки

Comment: Я теории не знаю, особенно как ее преподают. Но могу предположить, что при страничной организации требуется суммарный объем программы округленный верх до размера страницы (4000)+таблица страниц. При сегментной просто размер программы (3200)+таблица сегментов. Вариант C 4000+2 таблицы, если каждый сегмент не должен выравниваться на размер страницы. Правда на практике программе еще нужен сегмент данных и возможно стек, но в вашей теории про это видимо принято не вспоминать. И еще на практике сегменты могут то же ограничиваться кратностью какому то размеру

Comment: Отталкивайтесь от вашей методички. В реальной жизни кроме библиотечных процедур процедур, есть ещё стартовый/финализирующий код, глобальные переменные и т. п., ну и процедуры вовсе не обязаны грузиться в память в точности одна за одной.